# Meaning of "common method bias"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of *common method bias* in the sentence below?

> A second limitation concerns the fact that we only used self-report
>   questionnaires. **Common method bias** may thus have influenced some of
>   the results.

Comment: you might get a better result if you ask in the chat of the [cognitive sciences](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2250/the-axon-terminal) Stack Exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StatWiki](http://statwiki.kolobkreations.com/wiki/Confirmatory_Factor_Analysis#Common_Method_Bias_.28CMB.29) explains that:

> Common method bias refers to a bias in your dataset due to something
>   external to the measures.

In other words, the measured difference is due to the study itself (or something else), rather than the actuality of the situation.

The bias can occur because of the way the questions are constructed, the way in which they're asked, the audience to which they're asked, etc.

In the example OP gives, self-reporting is the source of the bias; the reasons the results of such a questionnaire are compromised are explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-report_study).